# Printing Wrong version Number when i run ssh -V

Tags: ssh, openssl, openssh, qnx

I am upgrading the `openssl` & `openssh` versions for `QNX` platform, from `openssl 1.0.0e` to `1.0.1g` & `openssh-5.6p1` to `openssh-6.6p1`
So using my linux machine I am cross compiling to generate binaries for `QNX`.
After doing all the steps mentioned below when i run `./ssh -V` i am getting this output

```
OpenSSH_6.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
```

But I used `openssl 1.0.1g` to generate `ssh` binaries.
Can any one tell me from where i am getting the version wrong?

Steps:
 Downloaded `openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz` & `openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz` and then `untar` it.
 2. `cd openssl-1.0.1g` & run this `config` command

```
CC=qcc CXX=qcc AR=nto${I_CPU}-ar LD=qcc RANLIB=nto${I_CPU}-ranlib CFLAGS+="-Vgcc_nto${I_CPU} -fPIC -DPIC" LDFLAGS+="-Vgcc_nto${I_CPU} -shared" ./Configure QNX6-i386 -shared --prefix=/home/vamsi/build_ppc --openssldir=/home/vamsi/build_ppc/openssl_dir
```

1. Make clean
2. Make
3. Make install
4. `cd openssh-6.6p1` & run this `config` command

   CC=qcc CFLAGS="-Vgcc_nto${I_CPUX} -L/home/vamsi/build_ppc/lib" AR=nto${I_CPUX}-ar LD=qcc LDFLAGS="-Vgcc_nto${I_CPUX} -L/home/vamsi/build_ppc/lib" CXX=qcc CPPFLAGS+="-DMISSING_HOWMANY -DMISSING_NFDBITS -DMISSING_NFDMASK" ./configure --disable-lastlog --host=ppcbe --with-ssl-dir=/home/vamsi/build_ppc/openssl_dir --prefix=/home/vamsi/build_ppc --disable-etc-default-login
5. make clean
6. make

After these steps i copied generated `ssh` binary file into target machine and tried to run `./ssh -V`

Also when i copied `openssl` Binary to target `QNX` machine and tried to execute this command

```
./openssl
```

It is giving this error

```
./openssl[1]: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

Note : I am not installing ssh in the target machine but i just want new version `ssh` binaries so i am running `./ssh -V` instead of `ssh -V`

I am able to successfully connect to any address using this `ssh` (generated binary).
and in making this Binary i am getting this warning

```
skipping incompatible /home/vamsi/build_ppc/lib/libcrypto.a when searching for -lcrypto
```

Has this warning got anything to do with the problem i am facing ??

I tried using openssl version 1.0.0l but still the output of ssh -v is showing as

OpenSSH_6.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007

Comment: I've removed the `ssl` tag, since you're not talking about SSL, but SSH (which doesn't rely on SSL).

Answer (score 0):

> After these steps i copied generated ssh binary file into target
>   machine and tried to run ./ssh -V
>
> Also when i copied openssl Binary to target QNX machine

This and the [comments you've posted on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23802393/372643) about the output of `ldd`: "*It is taking the previous libraries instead of newly generated ones in creating the binaries.*" seem to suggest you have only copied these two executable files, but not the libraries you've compiled.

You don't need the `openssl` command to use `ssh`, but you'll need the OpenSSL libraries (`libssl.something.so`).

If you want to test this in a local directory instead of overwriting your system's libraries (which I'd recommend, since you don't seem quite sure how this all works), consider using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the path where you've installed those libraries.

In general, it would be a good idea to read about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. On Linux, I'd also look at using `ldconfig`, but [I'm not sure if there's an equivalent on QNX](http://www.openqnx.com/phpbbforum/viewtopic.php?t=10337).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One thing is QNX has 2 Platforms i.e.x86 & ppc(at least we use..). In x86 the out put for ssh -V is correct(OpenSSH_6.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1g). Even though i Haven't Copied Libraries into x86 platform.in that case it should show wrong version in x86 also right??